# Uninstall Adobe Flash C4 from mac

Tags: macos, uninstall, adobe-cs4, adobe-flash

I've installed a trial of Adobe Flash CS4 (i didn't use this trial till the end) and wrongly entered the expired license number. I ran uninstall and tried to install a trial version again. Seems, that it keeps somewhere the wrong serial number and each time i run the Flash application it alerts me, that the license has expired. How do i properly install the trial? Do i have a chance at all?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't anything you're doing wrong. This is a "feature" of the Adobe licensing to prevent you from re-using trial software.

A quick google search revealed [this link, showing a cache file you can delete](http://machacks.tv/2009/01/26/defeating-the-adobe-cs4-license-expired-dialog-in-os-x/) to get around your issue.

Comment: nope, I don't have a folder /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe PCD/cache/cache.db. I'm running Snow Leopard. Other ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm personally out of ideas. Considering what you're attempting to do is likely against the EULA for all the Adobe software, I'm not sure how much support you could get on the issue.

Comment: I didn't enjoy my month trial, so why it's against EULA?

Comment: You had the software on your computer for a month, regardless of whether you used it or not. The license covers you to use it for that month and that month only, and to "reset" it is circumventing their licensing methods. If you can't find a solution, reinstalling Mac OS X is always one way to get the trial to reset.

Comment: You're right in case of Adobe that's probably the only way or, of course buy the software...